# Why don't we simplify spelling of "champagne" to something like "champen"

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

In modern (or American) ENglish, we simplified spellings of many words, such as plough, mould, neighbour, and many many more. Why don't we do same thing for word "champagne"?

Comment: Well, the "simplified" spelling would not be "champen" -- it would be something closer to "champain".  But the "foreign" spelling is part of the mystique of the beverage, so the name's never going to change.

Comment: The issue of semplifing the spelling of English terms is an old and controversial one:  ***English-language spelling reform*** - *For centuries there has been a movement to reform the spelling of English. It seeks to change English spelling so that it is more consistent, matches pronunciation better, and follows the alphabetic principle.* https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform

Comment: Why don't we simplify it? Because we are not allowed to do that. Why don't we simplify "neighbour" to "neibor" or "nabor"? Champagne is not an English word. We can't change the spelling of Johannesburg, Mississippi or Massachusetts

Comment: @Rathony - the "semplificatin" of geographic terms is actually the more common one...Roma is Rome, Milano is Milan...just to name a few.

Comment: Anglicizing and simplifying aren't the same thing.

Comment: Who is "**we**"? Who would you like to perform such simplification, and how? English does not have the equivalent of the Academie Francaise. No one body controls the evolution of English.

Comment: No one would pay $500 for a bottle of champen.

Comment: Why would you change it so it's pronounced like 'dampen'?

Comment: Calling it _Champen_ would take all the _joy-day-veev-ray_ out of it _toot day sweet_.

Comment: Spanish respells imported words so they make sense, so they have *champán* there, but English does not.

Comment: Why don't whoever 'we' are decide that it's time that 'theater' should totally replace 'theatre'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Because the live theater people have decided that "theatre" has more cachet.

Comment: @tchrist - Yeah, I was told, ca 1963, that a Spanish commission of some sort rapidly changes the spelling of words to match changing pronunciation, keeping the language rigorously phonetic.

Comment: @Josh61 but what about *Leghorn* for Livorno? What's so difficult about pronouncing or spelling *Livorno*? And *Florence* for *Firenze*? *Sicily* for *Sicilia*? The "ci" in English is pronounced *si*, (Sisily) completely different from Italian, where "ci" is pronounced *chi* as in "chips". Logic or simplification does not govern English spelling where writing geographical names are concerned.

Comment: Florence and Sicily are by any measure more English in spelling and pronunciation than Firenze and Sicilia, which English speaking people can't even guess how to pronounce them.

Answer (score 3):

Because Champagne is the name of the region in France where the sparkling wine comes from. You don't just change the names of people or places without their consent.

In most cases Champagne the drink must come from Champagne the place to be called that. In those places where this is not the case, nobody will put 'champen' on their bottles as it would be a very easy way to tell the knock-off from the original.